# how make Laravel pagination vue js

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, vuejs2, axios

How to build pagination on vue.js? My paging request to the API Laravel paginate:

```
->Paginate(10)
```

I build my app with vuejs CDN. Can I use HTTP REQUEST with Axios?

Comment: I think you need to integrate this git plugin https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination

Comment: i am not use npm, i use vue js CDN